# (Oracle Database 11g Express Edition )(PyCharm)(RobotFramework) DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: testing, oracle11g, pycharm, robotframework

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle DB (i'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3 x64) and i'v got an error: DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I was trying to figure out a issue on my own but nothing works.

PYCHARM:

```
Documentation  Basic database related keywords
Library  DatabaseLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem
*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING} =  'SYSTEM/SYSTEM(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xe))'

*** Test Cases ***
Connecting
  connect

  @{queryResults}  Query  select * from table AQ$_INTERNET_AGENTS

  log to console  @{queryResults}

*** Keywords ***
connect
    connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle  ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

Disconnect
    disconnect from database
```

ERROR:

```
Test2 :: Basic database related keywords
==============================================================================
Connecting                                                            | FAIL |
DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2 :: Basic database related keywords                              | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Comment: Do not attach screenshots and images. Please update your question to include formatted _text_ of your code and any errors you are receiving.

Comment: You are getting an "invalid password" error, so your database information in the connect string is correct and you are reaching the database instance. SYSTEM is a default account, so the only conclusion remaining is that the password is incorrect.